# Configure fail when build the pam_sasl module

Tags: linux, pam

I downloaded pam_sasl source code from 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pam-sasl/?source=typ_redirect

After issue ./configure command, it returns configure: error: sasl2 not found

```
linux-xbx0:~/pam_sasl-0.1.2 # ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for xsltproc... /usr/bin/xsltproc
checking for sasl_checkpass in -lsasl2... no
configure: error: sasl2 not found

linux-xbx0:~/pam_sasl-0.1.2 # rpm -ql libsasl2-3-2.1.26-7.1.x86_64
/usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.3
/usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.3.0.0

linux-xbx0:~/pam_sasl-0.1.2 # echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
:/usr/lib:/usr/lib64:/usr/lib:/usr/lib64:/usr/lib/sasl2/:/usr/lib64/sasl2

linux-xbx0:~/pam_sasl-0.1.2 # rpm -qa | grep sasl
cyrus-sasl-sqlauxprop-32bit-2.1.26-7.1.x86_64
cyrus-sasl-gssapi-2.1.26-7.1.x86_64
libsasl2-3-2.1.26-7.1.x86_64
libsasl2-3-32bit-2.1.26-7.1.x86_64
cyrus-sasl-saslauthd-2.1.26-7.1.x86_64
cyrus-sasl-crammd5-2.1.26-7.1.x86_64
cyrus-sasl-otp-2.1.26-7.1.x86_64
cyrus-sasl-32bit-2.1.26-7.1.x86_64
cyrus-sasl-digestmd5-2.1.26-7.1.x86_64
cyrus-sasl-gssapi-32bit-2.1.26-7.1.x86_64
cyrus-sasl-plain-32bit-2.1.26-7.1.x86_64
cyrus-sasl-sqlauxprop-2.1.26-7.1.x86_64
cyrus-sasl-plain-2.1.26-7.1.x86_64
cyrus-sasl-otp-32bit-2.1.26-7.1.x86_64
cyrus-sasl-2.1.26-7.1.x86_64
cyrus-sasl-crammd5-32bit-2.1.26-7.1.x86_64
```

linux-xbx0:~/pam_sasl-0.1.2 # cat /etc/*release 
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 (x86_64) VERSION = 12 PATCHLEVEL = 1

Comment: You need to install the additional development package for the SASL2 library.

Comment: hi, Arkascha, thanks for your advise. I have installed all *sasl* rpm from OS DVD. Do you know which rpm is needed?

Comment: *cyrus-sasl-devel* would be a likely candidate.

Comment: Thank you JJ, I find that rpm, and now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Development packages corresponding to the "normal" packages usually have a `-devel` appended to their name. Since the `SASL2` library is provided by the package `cyrus-sasl` you are now looking for the package `cyrus-sasl-devel`.

Since you are using an openSUSE distribution derivate, here SLES, you can use either the provided software management utility, `YaST` to install that package, or the command line tool `zypper` if installed, which is much faster in use. So you have these two alternatives:

1. launch the `YaST` control center, chose the "Software Management" module, wait until it is loaded. Then search for the string "sasl" and pick the package from the list of hits.
2. `zypper install cyrus-sasl-devel`